# Installing TexLive on CentOS5 via SSH

Tags: linux, latex, ssh, centos

I am trying to install TexLive remotely via command line SSH on a computer running CentOS5.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Fedora RPM for Texlive 2011, but I think none for CentOS.

The right way, then, is to install from source, for which there are a number of options, with the network install recommended.  The link to the tarball and instructions on how to start are given at [the Texlive net install page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).  This install route gives you the option to install via an ncurses-based interface, which works fine over ssh.

This gives you a very nice installation, but the downside compared to, say, installing the outdated Tetex RPM is that zum does not know that you have Latex installed.